# Remove Count column by repeating rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate, google-sheets-arrays

I have a worksheet, 'wi', in a Google Sheet similar to the following example but with an undetermined number of rows:

```
  Count | Entry |   Description   
 -------|-------|----------------- 
      2 | Foo   | yada yada       
      3 | Bar   | blah blah blah
```

On another worksheet I want to repeat each (not the header) in 'wi' by the Count such that:

```
  Entry |   Description   
 -------|----------------- 
  Foo   | yada yada       
  Foo   | yada yada       
  Bar   | blah blah blah  
  Bar   | blah blah blah  
  Bar   | blah blah blah
```

A custom formula is better than a gnarly formula composition but a solution of existing built-ins that is clean and manageable is preferred over code.

Comment: Maybe try this kind of solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037640/how-to-make-a-range-repeat-n-times-in-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, i had gotten to =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(wi!B2:B&"==",wi!A2:A), "==")) but if I try to transpose the split, I get "result was not automatically expanded, please insert more columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With arrays you can do it :

```
  Count | Entry |   Description   
 -------|-------|----------------- 
      2 | Foo   | yada yada       
      3 | Bar   | blah blah blah
```

Using this with "**Count**" in `A1`; "**Description**" in `C1`; etc..

```
={B1:C1; transpose(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(transpose(ArrayFormula((REPT(B2:C2&",",A2)))),",",true,true)));transpose(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(transpose(ArrayFormula((REPT(B3:C3&",",A3)))),",",true,true)))}
```

Result :

```
  Entry |   Description   
 -------|----------------- 
   Foo  | yada yada  
   Foo  | yada yada 
   Bar  | blah blah blah
   Bar  | blah blah blah
   Bar  | blah blah blah
```

[Working example in `A5`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WgvemKnsMc1IL_Cu9g8PqXCNzCKH3v7r0QrUU-_3muY/edit#gid=0)

Edit : New solution using column

```
    =transpose(split(TEXTJOIN(",",true,transpose(ArrayFormula(REPT(B2:B100&",",$A2:$A100)))),",",true,true))
```

Now to use it you juste have to expand it on every column. Don't forget to modify the range I used (`B2:B100` and `$A2:$A100`)

Edit 2 : Added some check in case a cell from the original range is blank :

`=transpose(split(TEXTJOIN(",",true,transpose(ArrayFormula(REPT(ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B4<>"",B2:B4,"BLANK CELL"))&",",$A2:$A4)))),",",true,true))`

Don't forget to expand it for every column.

Comment: I do not quite understand the answer and "copy paste" does not work. Can you break it down for me?

Comment: It can depends on your spreadsheet settings, the first issue that comes in my mind is if  you do use `,` or `;` in formulas. I'll break down my answer tomorrow but TL;DR: I used `REPT` to repeat the strings (with `arrayformula` because range is an array)  then `SPLIT` to divide the string in separate cells (again with `arrayformula` 'cause the range is an array). `TRANSPOSE` is very useful because arrayformula only works in column, you can test it by yourself.      

Finally I used `{}` to put everything in an unique formula. Is the working example ok btw ?

Comment: Thanks. It does work if I only use it on two source rows or add a sub-formula for each row - in my case about 100 but it fluctuates.  How can this work for an arbitrary number of source rows?

Comment: Edit : I added a new solution where you just have to expand the formula with a drag on every column, you can check it on the updated sheet example. (Cells highlighted in yellow contain formula)

Comment: Ok, so the columns with expanding array formulas get out of sync with the description not matching the entry.

Comment: Yes it happens if an entry or a description is blank. You can add some check with `arrayformula(IF(range is blank, "no content",range))` instead of the range. I updated the example and my answer

Comment: Thank you. This does answer the question although an appscript is starting to look more manageable :D  FYI if the count is 1, ie the row does not repeat, i get an extra comma at the beginning of the entry.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 REPT({wi!B2:B&"♦"&wi!C2:C}&"♥", wi!A2:A)), "♥")), "♦"))
```

[image]