# Split comma-separated cell in sheets while repeating other cell for all entries

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Sheet that looks like this:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════════════════════════╦══╗
║  ID   ║                Users                ║  ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬══╣
║ 12345 ║ bob@domain.com,su'uzan@domain.com   ║  ║
║ 99999 ║ steven@domain.com,rachel@domain.com ║  ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════════════════════════╩══╝
```

It's two column, one with an ID and one with comma-separated lists of emails. I need to look like this:

```
╔═══════╦════════════════════╦══╗
║  ID   ║       Users        ║  ║
╠═══════╬════════════════════╬══╣
║ 12345 ║ bob@domain.com     ║  ║
║ 12345 ║ su'uzan@domain.com ║  ║
║ 99999 ║ steven@domain.com  ║  ║
║ 99999 ║ rachel@domain.com  ║  ║
╚═══════╩════════════════════╩══╝
```

I've tried using pivot tables and some `query` operations but haven't been able to crack it. There's roughly 6,000 entries in the Sheet now. I also wasn't able to get anything from [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e) to work (I need something automatic, there's too much data to do manually.) [This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98529/split-contents-of-comma-separated-cell-and-send-to-new-rows-with-adjacent-cell) also seems similar but is unanswered.

Comment: Did you try this : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132984/remove-count-column-by-repeating-rows-in-google-sheets ?

Comment: The first link points to a question with several answers, some of them include scripts  and other formulas. What do you meant by "I need something authomatic"? Which solutions you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Here is another related question [Convert the data from comma-separated cells into repeated rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95635/88163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the [excellent code](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/62476/117311) provided by [Jacob Jan Tuinstra](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/29140/jacob-jan-tuinstra) to fit your needs assuming your data starts at `A2`.

#### Step 1

Open the `Script editor` from your sheet menu and paste this code:

```
function result(range) {
  var output2 = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = range.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][1].split(",");    
    for(var j = 0, jLen = s.length; j < jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k = 0, kLen = range[0].length; k < kLen; k++) {
        if(k == 1) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

#### Step 2

Paste anywhere (`D1` or `G1` or...) this formula: `=result(A2:B5)`

#### Step 3

Done

> *...wasn't able to get anything from [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/62476/117311) to work I
>   need something automatic...*

I believe it doesn't get more automatic.

*If for any reason you cannot get it to work, please share the link to a test sheet in a comment so we can work it out.*

Comment: I was able to modify this to get it to work, thanks!